# Jest testing a service that uses Neo4J and MongoDb returns error: "TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'inspectModules')"

Tags: typescript, mongodb, testing, neo4j, jestjs

I have a service that runs a query to Mongodb and Neo4j. The create method runs two methods: "CreateUserInMongoDB" and "CreateUserInNeo4j". The code is provided below:

```
export class UserService {
  constructor(
    @InjectModel('User') private readonly userModel: Model<UserDocument>,
    @InjectModel('SportEvent')
    private readonly sportEventModel: Model<SportEventDocument>,
    private readonly neo4jQueryService: Neo4jQueryService
  ) {}

  //creating a user.
  async create(user: User): Promise<object> {
    let userInMongoDB: { mongoId: string; firstName: string };
    try {
      userInMongoDB = await this.createUserInMongoDB(user);
      const userIncreaeNeo4j = await this.createUserInNeo4j(
        userInMongoDB.firstName,
        userInMongoDB.mongoId
      );
      if (userIncreaeNeo4j && userInMongoDB) {
        return {
          statusCode: 201,
          message: `User succesfully created`,
        };
      }
    } catch (error) {
      if (userInMongoDB) {
        await this.userModel.findByIdAndDelete(userInMongoDB.mongoId).lean();
      }
      throw new HttpException(error.message, 400);
    }
  }

  //create user in mongoDB
  async createUserInMongoDB(
    user: User
  ): Promise<{ mongoId: string; firstName: string }> {
    try {
      const createdUser = new this.userModel(user);
      createdUser.email = user.email.toLowerCase();
      createdUser.firstName = user.firstName.toLowerCase();
      createdUser.lastName = user.lastName.toLowerCase();

      console.log(user);

      await createdUser.save();
      const userInMongoDB = {
        mongoId: createdUser._id.toString(),
        firstName: createdUser.firstName,
      };
      return userInMongoDB;
    } catch (error) {
      if (error.code === 11000) {
        throw new HttpException(
          'Duplicate entry, email has to be unique.',
          409
        );
      } else {
        throw new HttpException(error.message, 400);
      }
    }
  }

  //create user in neo4j
  async createUserInNeo4j(userName: string, userId: string): Promise<boolean> {
    try {
      await this.neo4jQueryService.write(
        `CREATE (n:User {mongoId: "${userId}", name: "${userName}"}) RETURN n`
      );
      return true;
    } catch (error) {
      throw new HttpException(error.message, 400);
    }
  }
```

Im trying to test the code above. The test im trying to do is simple, i just want to test if the userService is defined:

```
import { Test, TestingModule } from '@nestjs/testing';
import { getModelToken } from '@nestjs/mongoose';
import { Model } from 'mongoose';
import { UserService } from '../user.service';
import { Neo4jQueryService } from '../../../neo4-j/neo4-j.service';
import { UserDocument } from '../../Schemas/user.schema';
import { User } from '@sport-activity-app/domain';
import { HttpException } from '@nestjs/common';

describe('UserService', () => {
  let userService: UserService;
  let userModel: Model<UserDocument>;
  let neo4jQueryService: Neo4jQueryService;

  beforeEach(async () => {
    const module: TestingModule = await Test.createTestingModule({
      providers: [
        UserService,
        Neo4jQueryService,
        {
          provide: getModelToken('User'),
          useValue: {
            // mock Mongoose Model methods used in the UserService class
            findByIdAndDelete: jest.fn(),
            create: jest.fn(),
          },
        },
        {
          provide: getModelToken('SportEvent'),
          useValue: {
            // mock Mongoose Model methods used in the UserService class
          },
        },
      ],
    }).compile();

    userService = module.get<UserService>(UserService);
    userModel = module.get<Model<UserDocument>>(getModelToken('User'));
    neo4jQueryService = module.get<Neo4jQueryService>(Neo4jQueryService);
  });

  it('should be defined', () => {
    expect(userService).toBeDefined();
  });
});
```

The error i get is: "TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'inspectModules')".
Im clueless what is happening. Does anyone know?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Upgrade to version '@nestjs/testing': ^9.3.12

Comment: Thanks, i had figured it already but had forgotten to update this post. Ill give you the credits anyway.

Answer (score 0):

[UPDATED]

That error indicates that there is a statement somewhere (possibly in a library) that looks something like this (where `foo` is undefined):

```
foo.inspectModules(...)
```

If you have this in your code, fix it. If it is not in your code, see if you are using the right library versions or if there are more recent versions that you can use.